# iOS/tvOS How to prevent User Interface blocking when objects are being deallocated

Tags: ios, swift, memory, tvos

I am having a little responsiveness issue in an app I'm working on.

I am using a subclass of an `AVQueuePlayer` which adds a few basic features to the `AVQueuePlayer` to fit my needs. These features require me to keep an array of all `AVPlayerItems` in memory while the subclass is still active (mainly because I want to be able to jump freely between `AVPlayerItems` at any time).

When I dismiss the ViewController containing the `AVQueuePlayer` subclass all of the memory gets deallocated. However, depending on the amount of `AVPlayerItems` in the items array this can take quite a few seconds during which any UI interaction is blocked.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find any way to move these deallocations to the background. I tried keeping a reference to the objects in another viewController and set them nil using a dispatch_async call to a background thread. However, that still blocks any user interaction just as if I did it on the main thread or without keeping that additional reference.

I am grateful for any tip/hint in the right direction. I would really like to get rid of this.